# Awk: From CSV to PDB (Protein Data Bank)

Tags: if-statement, awk, printf

I have a CSV file with this format:

```
ATOM,3662,H,VAL,A,257,6.111,31.650,13.338,1.00,0.00,H
ATOM,3663,HA,VAL,A,257,3.180,31.995,13.768,1.00,0.00,H
ATOM,3664,HB,VAL,A,257,4.726,32.321,11.170,1.00,0.00,H
ATOM,3665,HG11,VAL,A,257,2.387,31.587,10.892,1.00,0.00,H
```

And I would like to format it according to PDB standards (fixed position):

```
ATOM   3662  H   VAL A 257       6.111  31.650  13.338  1.00  0.00           H

ATOM   3663  HA  VAL A 257       3.180  31.995  13.768  1.00  0.00           H

ATOM   3664  HB  VAL A 257       4.726  32.321  11.170  1.00  0.00           H

ATOM   3665 HG11 VAL A 257       2.387  31.587  10.892  1.00  0.00           H
```

One can consider that everything is right-justified except for the first and the third column. The first is not a problem. The third however, it is left-justified when it length is 1-3 but shifted one position to the left when it is 4.

I have this AWK one-liner that almost does the trick:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {if(length($3) == 4 ) {pad=" "} else {pad="  "}} {printf "%-6s%5s%s%-4s%4s%2s%4s%11s%8s%8s%6s%6s%12s\n", $1, $2, $pad, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12}' < 1iy8_min.csv
```

Except for two things:

1. The exception of the third column. I was thinking about adding a condition which changes the padding before the third column according to the field length, but I cannot get it to work (the idea is illustrated in the above one-liner).
2. The other problem is that if there are no spaces between the fields, the padding does not work at all.

   ```
   ATOM   3799  HH   TYR A 267     -5.713  16.149  26.838  1.00  0.00           H

   HETATM 3801  O7N  NADA12688.285     19.839  10.489    1.00 20.51     O
   ```

In the above example, the second line should be:

```
HETATM 3801  O7N  NAD A1268      8.285  19.839  10.489  1.00 20.51           O
```

But because there is no space between fields 5 and 6, everything gets shuffled. It think that A1268 is perceived as being one field. Maybe because the default awk delimiter seems to be a blank space. Is it possible to make it position-dependent?

UPDATE: The following solves the problem with the exception on the third column:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ",";OFS = ""} { if(length($3) == 4 ) {pad = sprintf("%s", " ")} else {pad = sprintf("%2s", " ")} } { if(length($3) == 4 ) {pad2 = sprintf("%s", " ")} else {pad2 = sprintf("%s", "")} } {printf "%-6s%5s%s%-4s%s%3s%2s%4s%11s%8s%8s%6s%6s%12s\n", $1, $2, pad, $3, pad2, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12}' 1iy8_min.csv
```

However, OFS seems to be ignored...

UPDATE2: The problem was in the input file. Sorry about that. Solved.

The working script:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{$7=sprintf("%.3f",$7)}1{$8=sprintf("%.3f",$8)}1{$9=sprintf("%.3f",$9)}1' ${file} | awk 'BEGIN {FS =","; OFS=""} { if(length($3) == 4 ) {pad = sprintf("%s", " ")} else {pad = sprintf("%2s", " ")} } { if(length($3) == 4 ) {pad2 = sprintf("%s", " ")} else {pad2 = sprintf("%s", "")} } {printf "%-6s%5s%s%-4s%s%3s%2s%4s%12s%8s%8s%6s%6s%12s\n", $1, $2, pad, $3, pad2, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12}' > ${root}_csv.pdb
```

Comment: When you use `$pad` in your script - awk is not shell and has it's own syntax. ITYM `pad` not `$pad`. Your text says `The third however, it is left-justified when it length is 1-3 but shifted one position to the left when it is 4` but your example seems to show the opposite of that - which is correct?

Comment: That extra stuff at the bottom of your question about handling a 5th field of `A1268` seems like it's enormously important and completely changes how the problem should be approached since it seems to imply that you must always have at least one blank between fields in which case your justification approach simply can't work on it's own and you need to add blank chars to the output formatting. Include a line like that in a second copy of your sample input and expected output so we can see how a line like that affects the formatting of the rest of your output.

Comment: I wonder who comes up with these strange file formats?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Ed, no I believe the example illustrates what I said. Thanks for the tip. No, the PDB format is position-based, spaces do not really matter.

Comment: Karakfa, the Protein Databank format has been used in the field of crystallography for decades. It is far from ideal, though.

Comment: @mirix - a) no, it doesn't, having a field longer than the field width you've shown us everywhere else is a game changer and b) wrt `OFS seems to be ignored` - you're not using it anywhere in your script so what were you expecting wrt OFS?